# ASP.NET and MongoDB - Not saving in the context of a Unit Test

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MongoDB and setting up a .NET C# MVC Project to try it out.

Using the current MongoDB.Driver 2.2.2 from nuget.

Issue:
I have a unit test that succeeds but does not save any data to the MongoDB Collection.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        IDatabase<Publisher> context = new MyProject.Data.Concrete.MongoDatabase<Publisher>("Publishers");
        Publisher pub = new Publisher()
        {
            Name = "Test"
        };
        context.Add(pub);
    }
```

However, if I put this same test under a MVC Controller it will save the data:

```
 public ActionResult Contact() {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        IDatabase<Publisher> context = new MyProject.Data.Concrete.MongoDatabase<Publisher>("Publishers");
        Publisher pub = new Publisher()
        {
            Name = "Test"
        };
        context.Add(pub);

        return View();
    }
```

I am curious as to why this is so?

Here is the MongoDatabase class:

```
 public class MongoDatabase<T> : IDatabase<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private static string _connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mongodb"].ConnectionString;
    private MongoClient _mongoClient = new MongoClient(_connectionString);

    private string _collectionName;
    private IMongoDatabase _db;

    protected IMongoCollection<T> _collection
    {
        get
        {
            return _db.GetCollection<T>(_collectionName);
        }
        set
        {
            _collection = value;
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Query
    {
        get
        {
            return _collection.AsQueryable<T>();
        }
        set
        {
            Query = value;
        }
    }

    public MongoDatabase(string collectionName)
    {
        _collectionName = collectionName;
        _db = _mongoClient.GetDatabase(MongoUrl.Create(_connectionString).DatabaseName);
    }


    public bool Add(T item)
    {
        var result = _collection.InsertOneAsync(item);

        //return result. what can we use here?
        return true;
    }

    public int Add(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        int count = 0;

        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            if (Add(item))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You should change calls for async methods.

```
public async Task Add(T item)
{
    await _collection.InsertOneAsync(item);
}
```

You can read more about [async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

2)

> //return result. what can we use here?
>   return true;

You don't need to return bool. You need to have exception handler on a top level.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I made this change - it had no effect on unit test. Problem still exists.